# How to run gitversion within a container without bind-mounting host to same path in container?

Tags: docker, filesystems, docker-in-docker, gitversion

I use *gitversion* [through Docker](https://gitversion.net/docs/usage/cli/installation) like so (I'll use *jsoncpp* as an example target repo that I want to run *gitversion* on):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp.git
Cloning into 'jsoncpp'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 8540, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (122/122), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (78/78), done.
remote: Total 8540 (delta 62), reused 73 (delta 40), pack-reused 8418
Receiving objects: 100% (8540/8540), 2.88 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5400/5400), done.
$ cd jsoncpp/
$ docker run -u $(id -u ${USER}):$(id -g ${USER}) --rm -v "$(pwd):/repo" gittools/gitversion:5.6.6 /repo
{
  "Major": 1,
  "Minor": 9,
  "Patch": 6,
  "PreReleaseTag": "",
  "PreReleaseTagWithDash": "",
  "PreReleaseLabel": "",
  "PreReleaseLabelWithDash": "",
  "PreReleaseNumber": null,
  "WeightedPreReleaseNumber": 60000,
  "BuildMetaData": 4,
  "BuildMetaDataPadded": "0004",
  "FullBuildMetaData": "4.Branch.master.Sha.8190e061bc2d95da37479a638aa2c9e483e58ec6",
  "MajorMinorPatch": "1.9.6",
  "SemVer": "1.9.6",
  "LegacySemVer": "1.9.6",
  "LegacySemVerPadded": "1.9.6",
  "AssemblySemVer": "1.9.6.0",
  "AssemblySemFileVer": "1.9.6.0",
  "FullSemVer": "1.9.6+4",
  "InformationalVersion": "1.9.6+4.Branch.master.Sha.8190e061bc2d95da37479a638aa2c9e483e58ec6",
  "BranchName": "master",
  "EscapedBranchName": "master",
  "Sha": "8190e061bc2d95da37479a638aa2c9e483e58ec6",
  "ShortSha": "8190e06",
  "NuGetVersionV2": "1.9.6",
  "NuGetVersion": "1.9.6",
  "NuGetPreReleaseTagV2": "",
  "NuGetPreReleaseTag": "",
  "VersionSourceSha": "5defb4ed1a4293b8e2bf641e16b156fb9de498cc",
  "CommitsSinceVersionSource": 4,
  "CommitsSinceVersionSourcePadded": "0004",
  "UncommittedChanges": 0,
  "CommitDate": "2022-07-14"
}
```

More specifically, I need to run *gitversion* from within another running container.
The *Dockerfile* is:

```
FROM ubuntu as base

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y docker.io
```

...which I build like so:

```
$ docker build -t tmp:tmp .
[+] Building 0.1s (7/7) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 43B                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                              0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                               0.0s
 => [1/3] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [2/3] RUN apt-get update                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [3/3] RUN apt-get install -y docker.io                                              0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                         0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                        0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:244551624de072f0272463c4c5593e90cc0b4ded218487a3660e43e756d2049f   0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/tmp:tmp                                                     0.0s
```

The method I've learned to run "docker in docker" is to bind-mount the Docker host's file */var/run/docker.sock*. So I try to run *gitversion* inside my container like so:

```
$ docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -it tmp:tmp
root@4f5b71a95c23:/# mkdir /home/workspace
root@4f5b71a95c23:/# cd /home/workspace
root@4f5b71a95c23:/home/workspace# git clone https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp.git
Cloning into 'jsoncpp'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 8540, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (122/122), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (76/76), done.
remote: Total 8540 (delta 61), reused 76 (delta 42), pack-reused 8418
Receiving objects: 100% (8540/8540), 2.88 MiB | 19.04 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5398/5398), done.
root@4f5b71a95c23:/home/workspace# cd jsoncpp/
root@4f5b71a95c23:/home/workspace/jsoncpp# docker run -u $(id -u ${USER}):$(id -g ${USER}) --rm -v "$(pwd):/repo" gittools/gitversion:5.6.6 /repo
Cannot find the .git directory
```

...which fails with a "Cannot find the .git directory" error.

So far, I had worked around this by bind-mounting a host directory to the same directory in the container, then working within that directory, like so:

```
$ docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /tmp/:/tmp/ -it tmp:tmp
root@8101580ff741:/# mkdir /tmp/workspace
root@8101580ff741:/# cd /tmp/workspace/
root@8101580ff741:/tmp/workspace# git clone https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp.git
Cloning into 'jsoncpp'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 8540, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (122/122), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (76/76), done.
remote: Total 8540 (delta 61), reused 76 (delta 42), pack-reused 8418
Receiving objects: 100% (8540/8540), 2.88 MiB | 18.33 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5398/5398), done.
root@8101580ff741:/tmp/workspace# cd jsoncpp/
root@8101580ff741:/tmp/workspace/jsoncpp# docker run -u $(id -u ${USER}):$(id -g ${USER}) --rm -v "$(pwd):/repo" gittools/gitversion:5.6.6 /repo
{
  "Major": 1,
  "Minor": 9,
  "Patch": 6,
  "PreReleaseTag": "",
  "PreReleaseTagWithDash": "",
  "PreReleaseLabel": "",
  "PreReleaseLabelWithDash": "",
  "PreReleaseNumber": null,
  "WeightedPreReleaseNumber": 60000,
  "BuildMetaData": 4,
  "BuildMetaDataPadded": "0004",
  "FullBuildMetaData": "4.Branch.master.Sha.8190e061bc2d95da37479a638aa2c9e483e58ec6",
  "MajorMinorPatch": "1.9.6",
  "SemVer": "1.9.6",
  "LegacySemVer": "1.9.6",
  "LegacySemVerPadded": "1.9.6",
  "AssemblySemVer": "1.9.6.0",
  "AssemblySemFileVer": "1.9.6.0",
  "FullSemVer": "1.9.6+4",
  "InformationalVersion": "1.9.6+4.Branch.master.Sha.8190e061bc2d95da37479a638aa2c9e483e58ec6",
  "BranchName": "master",
  "EscapedBranchName": "master",
  "Sha": "8190e061bc2d95da37479a638aa2c9e483e58ec6",
  "ShortSha": "8190e06",
  "NuGetVersionV2": "1.9.6",
  "NuGetVersion": "1.9.6",
  "NuGetPreReleaseTagV2": "",
  "NuGetPreReleaseTag": "",
  "VersionSourceSha": "5defb4ed1a4293b8e2bf641e16b156fb9de498cc",
  "CommitsSinceVersionSource": 4,
  "CommitsSinceVersionSourcePadded": "0004",
  "UncommittedChanges": 0,
  "CommitDate": "2022-07-14"
}
```

The noted workaround is no longer acceptable; I can't place my finger on it, but it feels kludgy: it's using a real host directory as a written-to location, meaning work that's intended to only be internal to the running container leaves artifacts on the host.

Also, the workaround only works if I bind-mount the Docker host directory to the same directory inside the container. I.e. `-v /tmp:/tmp` works, but `-v /tmp:/foo`, then working in */foo* in the running container results in the "Cannot find the .git directory" error:

```
$ docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /tmp:/foo -it tmp:tmp
root@799fef66a7d5:/# cd /foo
root@799fef66a7d5:/foo# mkdir workspace
root@799fef66a7d5:/foo# git clone https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp.git
Cloning into 'jsoncpp'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 8540, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (122/122), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (79/79), done.
remote: Total 8540 (delta 62), reused 72 (delta 39), pack-reused 8418
Receiving objects: 100% (8540/8540), 2.88 MiB | 940.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5399/5399), done.
root@799fef66a7d5:/foo# cd jsoncpp/
root@799fef66a7d5:/foo/jsoncpp# docker run -u $(id -u ${USER}):$(id -g ${USER}) --rm -v "$(pwd):/repo" gittools/gitversion:5.6.6 /repo
Cannot find the .git directory
```

**Questions:**
Why doesn't *gitversion* work if I run it against a target directory that's not rooted in a directory that also exists in the Docker host?

I feel as though there's a more generic problem behind my specific problem: something along the lines of "when you run docker-in-docker, the "internal" container can't access directories that don't exist at the same filepath on the Docker host" -- can someone please explain the underlying problem behind what I've described above?

Is there a different way/best practice for how to solve this problem? Is there a solution that doesn't require bind-mounting anything from the Docker host (other that */var/run/docker.sock*)?

Comment: You might find this tool easier to run without Docker.  Installing the .NET runtime on Linux might be a challenge, but otherwise, tools that principally read and write host files don't benefit from Docker's core filesystem isolation features.  In your Dockerfile especially, install the tool directly in the Dockerfile; don't try to launch a secondary container (where you will have the file-path problems you describe, and where the operator is forced to give your container unrestricted root access over the whole host).

Comment: More generally, a `docker run -v` option is interpreted by wherever the actual Docker daemon is running (so a physical-host path with a mounted Docker socket, the remote system if you're using a remote Docker) and you cannot mount files from one container to another.  See for example [When mounting /var/run/docker.sock into a container, which file system is used for volume mounting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776298/when-mounting-var-run-docker-sock-into-a-container-which-file-system-is-used-f)

Comment: @DavidMaze - do you know of any resources how to install the .NET runtime on Linux? It was precisely because _gitversion_'s non-docker application is .NET-based, my advisors essentially advised "it's gonna be tough/impractical/impossible to install the .NET runtime in a Linux container, so don't even bother going down that road."